# Stripe payment express js :transaction details is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am following official stripe documentation for setting up the payment

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express ,everything works expected but couple of things is missing

1)Transaction details ie id,payment status etc

```
stripe.customers.create(body)
    .then(customer =>
      {
      console.log("customer",customer);  
      stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        description: "Sample Charge",
           currency: "usd",
           customer: customer.id
      }
      )
          } )
    .then(charge =>{ 
      console.log("charge",charge);
      res.render("charge.pug")
      }).catch(error=>{
         console.log("Error",error);
      });
  });
```

`console.log("charge",charge);` gives `undefined`

2) Do i need to protect the `POST` api ??

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
    let amount = 500;

    let body = {
      email: req.body.stripeEmail,
      source: req.body.stripeToken
   };

    stripe.customers.create(body)
    .then(customer =>
      {
      console.log("customer",customer);  
      stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        description: "Sample Charge",
           currency: "usd",
           customer: customer.id
      }
      )
          } )
    .then(charge =>{ 
      console.log("charge",charge);
      res.render("charge.pug")
      }).catch(error=>{
         console.log("Error",error);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return`:

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  let amount = 500;

  let body = {
    email: req.body.stripeEmail,
    source: req.body.stripeToken
 };

  stripe.customers.create(body)
    .then(customer => {
      console.log("customer",customer);  
      return stripe.charges.create({ // <-- return the Promise
        amount,
        description: "Sample Charge",
        currency: "usd",
        customer: customer.id
      })
    })
  .then(charge =>{ 
    console.log("charge",charge);
    res.render("charge.pug")
  })
  .catch(error => console.log("Error",error));
});
```

<s>And no you don't need to protect the route. You don't see online merchants protect their routes, however, typically they have some sort of "Checkout as Guest" option.</s>

Comment: But `app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {` is not stripe route which he wants to protect, this is his route and it should be protected  or it can be expose publicly which is highly risky

Answer (score 0):

> transaction details is missing

You are resolving promise of `stripe.customers.create(body)` twice and not on `stripe.charges.create` So to solve your first problem resolve promise(`.then()`) to `stripe.charges.create` as follows

```
stripe.customers.create(body)
    .then(customer => {
        console.log("customer", customer);
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount,
            description: "Sample Charge",
            currency: "usd",
            customer: customer.id
        }
        ).then(charge => {
            console.log("charge", charge); //Here you will get transaction info now
            res.render("charge.pug")
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error", error);
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error", error);
    });
  })`
```

> Do i need to protect the POST api ??

Yes. You should protect your each and every public API. You can use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) or any other oAUTH to protect your routes.